# Jenkins Pipeline - Can not reference variable from global variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a global variable in Jenkins that references variable `$HOME`

*Jenkins ver. 2.213, Pipeline 2.6*

[image]
it works well in Freestyle jobs I can validate with shell step

```
echo $HOME
echo $ANDROID_HOME

>>> /home/ubuntu
>>> /home/ubuntu/android/sdk
```

but in the Pipeline job `$HOME` part is not resolved and the same shell code produces a different result

```
echo $HOME
echo $ANDROID_HOME

>>> /home/ubuntu
>>> $HOME/android/sdk
```

I don't do any env setup steps and the `$ANDROID_HOME` variable is accessible, it's just incorrect in the pipelines.

How to properly use global variables in the pipeline jobs?

Comment: Could you please share your exact snippet of the pipeline? I just tested your case and this works fine having the global variable defined as you show - `sh "echo $HOME" ; sh "echo $ANDROID_HOME"`

Comment: That's actually the exact snippet

    steps {
        sh '''
        #!/bin/bash
        echo $HOME
        echo $ANDROID_HOME
        '''
    }

Comment: In the meantime, I evaluate the var into itself to resolve the `$HOME` part inside of it, but that's not a sustainable solution.

    `ANDROID_HOME=\`eval echo $ANDROID_HOME\``